# Set the scope of a self-written function to global in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, path

Assume I have written a function fun(a,b,c) in Matlab and saved it ..\My Documents\MATLAB\fun.m .
How can I make it available to all functions in Matlab.

In other words: What needs to be done in order to call this function from any other matlab-file (script, function) without being in the directory the file is stored in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this effect by adding the file to the path - http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~gerry/MATLAB/howTo/setMATLABpath.html#pathCommand

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own structured function library and install/uninstall to the MATLAB path with this library template:

https://github.com/tiborsimon/MATLAB-Library-System-template